# How to parse pipe delimited data returned by command FIND?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having a 5 GB text file which contains pipe `|` delimited data. Now I have to search for a user given phone number, which is the first data column or the first token of the delimited file containing the phone number, and print the entire row when the phone number matches in the file By using command like:

```
find "999999999" "F:\....\list.txt"
```

Now it returns the row containing the phone number and other details in a delimited by `|` form, e.g.

```
9999999999|Mark An****|....blah...|....Address...|...
```

My purpose is to select first token, second token and fourth token from that row and display it. I am not sure whether I can do it directly via **find** command. So I thought I will use the output of **find** as an input for further processing. Any suggestions would be welcome.

**Background**: Later I would like to create a windows UI as an interface for user to search phone numbers, but for now I just want to do it through a batch file. So I need this query working. I first thought of doing it via python but it was taking lot of time and seemed unnecessary as Windows has a **find** command for quick search and also I would be using windows systems only.

Comment: To process the output from another program (in your case `FIND`)  you should use  `FOR`, try a look at `FOR /?`

Comment: If the first four data columns are never empty, i.e. there is never `||` in the CSV file in first four data columns, you can get the result you want with `for /F "tokens=1,2,4 delims=|" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L /C:"999999999" "F:\....\list.txt"') do echo %%I^|%%J^|%%K`. Open a Windows [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window, run `findstr /?` and read the output help, then run `for /?` and read again the output help.

Comment: thanks @Mofi using `find` took me 7 min but using `findstr` as you suggested above took just 1 min to search through 6.7 million rows of data!

Comment: I would suggest that you do not use both `/L` and `/C`, only `FindStr /BL "9999999999|"` should be necessary, note the included delimiter character too! I might myself also use `"EOL=|Tokens=1,2,4Delims=|"`.

Comment: This is very easy in PowerShell using `Import-Csv`. Search for an example. There are many.

Comment: @lit my file is a .txt file can I still search it using PowerShell and will there be any speed improvement?

Comment: I cannot tell you if performance will improve or decline. PowerShell code would be easier to write and understand than the misappropriated `FOR` loop of cmd.exe. PowerShell 6+ runs on Linux, Mac, and even Windows. Microsoft has made it clear that the future of scripting is PowerShell.